# PowerBI report not rendering using embed token

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

embedConfig={{
type: 'report',
id: tab.Report_ID_AZ__c,
embedUrl: embedReportUrl(tab.Report_ID_AZ__c, tab.Group_ID_AZ__c),
accessToken: tab.powerBItoken,
tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
settings: {
panes: {
filters: {
expanded: false,
visible: true,
},
}
},
filters: tab.filterConfig,
}}
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

Answer (score 0):

The embed token specifies which Power BI content can be embedded and it needs to be generated by the REST API. You may have missed a comma or a quotation mark in your code. Try this:

```
embedUrl: embedReportUrl(tab.Report_ID_AZ__c, tab.Group_ID_AZ__c),
accessToken: tab.powerBItoken,
// tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
settings: {
  panes: {
    filters: {
      expanded: false,
      visible: true
    }
  }
},
```

If this does not work, you may have an authentication issue with your auth token or an access level issue with your dashboard. You can check the documentation for more details on how to generate and use embed tokens correctly.

Comment: Im getting the token from powerbi. during embed the token its throw JSON parser error. Attached the screenshot. But embed token works with other report. Only fail on particular report.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? I can't see the attached screenshot of error 